# Условное выражение с предикатами or и and неправильно работает

Tags: python, булева-алгебра, приоритет

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
if a == c or a == c + 1 or a == c - 1 and b == d or b == d + 1 or b == d - 1:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Пытаюсь решить задачку на ход ладьи. Вводится 4 значения и нужно узнать, может ли так сходить ладья. Описал все шаги ладьи, но при вводе 4322 выводится `YES`.

Почему не срабатывает условие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в приоритете операций.

Для того, чтобы понять как интерпретируется данная конструкция предлагаю ее упростить, заменив каждое сравнение результатом - `False` / `True`.

Получиться:

```
False or False or False and False or True or False
```

данная конструкция интерпретируется слева направо и первые четыре предиката:

```
False or False or False and False
```

можно упростить до единственного `False` - получится:

```
False or True or False
```

результатом будет `True`

---

**NOTE:** на будущее - если в строке сравнения присутствуют оба предиката `or` и `and` , то задавайте приоритет явно при помощи скобок:

```
print((False or False or False) and (False or True or False))
# False
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и развернутый ответ, теперь все понял.

Answer (score 0):

Условия работают правильно. При вводе 4322 выполняется b = d+1 (3=2+1). Поэтому выводится "yes".

Comment: А как быть с 4, если она пройдет if получится a == c+1 или c-1. а C у меня 2

Comment: Что значит "если она пройдет if"?

Comment: зайдет в if и выполнится условие

Comment: В иф всегда зайдёт. Это конкретное условие не выполнится. Не понятен вопрос.